# Infinite loop in Newton bisection

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

```
program main
implicit none
double precision x0, a, b
x0 = -3

call findzero(x0)

contains


function f(x)
implicit none
double precision x,f

f = SIN(x) - exp(-x)

end function

function fprime(x)
implicit none
double precision fprime, x

fprime = COS(x) + exp(-x)

end function

subroutine findbracket(x0,a,b)
implicit none
double precision x0, a, b
double precision fa, fb
double precision dx

dx = 0.001d0
a = x0
b = x0

do
fa = f(a)
fb = f(b)
!print*,"bracket[", a, b, "]"  

    a = a - dx

    if (fa*fb < 0) then
        exit
    end if

    b = b + dx

    if (fa*fb < 0) then
        exit
    end if

    dx = dx*2

end do

end subroutine


subroutine findzero(x0)
implicit none
double precision x0, a, b
double precision p, tol


while (x0 <11) do 
    x0 = -3 
    print*, "what is x0", x0
    call findbracket(x0,a,b)

    call newtonbisection (p,a,b,tol)
    print*, "this is x0, x", x0, p
    x0 = x0 + 1

end do

end subroutine
```

Using this subroutine I am trying to solve for the zeros of

`f(x) = sinx - e^-x`

with `x0 = -3, -2, ..., 10`.

I have working subroutines `findbracket` and `newtonbisection`. Using `findbracket` I intend to get [a,b] and using those a and b, I want to find p for each x0.

When I compile, my code falls into an infinite loop, I tried it with commenting out

```
call newtonbisection (p,a,b,tol)
```

so I assume the problem is with `findbracket`. But if I just use the subroutine to find `[a,b]` with `x0 = -3`, it works but not when I combine them.

Why do I have an infinite loop?

Comment: It looks like you don't end `subroutine findbracket` , is that a typo?

Comment: That is a type. I just edited. Sorry about that.

Comment: can you explain how you ever expect that last do loop to end?

Comment: Sorry about another terrible typo.. I've been trying many different way to resolve the issue and got confused little. I tried `while (x0 <11) do` so x0 =10 can be the last iteration, but I still had the same issue.

Comment: try `do x0 = -3,10`

Comment: problem with `do x0 = -3,10` is that x0, a parameter for findbracket, is double precision while it requires integer for loop variable

Comment: Your code has numerous syntax and precision problems. Please read http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html

Comment: ok, declare an integer loop counter say `ix` then do `x0=real(ix)` in the loop. the way you are doing it you should not have `x0=-3` inside the loop

Comment: And you still haven't followed the advice, given in a comment on one of the earlier versions of this question, to use indentation to reflect the structure of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's narrow this loop down:

```
 do while (x0 < 11)
    x0 = -3
    call findbracket(x0, a, b)
    x0 = x0 + 1
end do
```

This is a loop that gets executed as long as `x0` is smaller than eleven. Inside the loop, you explicitly set `x0` to minus 3, then call a subroutine that uses `x0`, finally increment `x0`

I didn't see any location inside the `findbracket` routine where the value of `x0` would be changed, so it will still be `-3` at the end of the call. Then it gets incremented by one, so it's now `-2`, which is still smaller than `11`, so the loop starts again. The first thing it does is to reset `x0` to `-3`, and the whole spiel starts at the same point again.

So the condition `x0 < 11` will always be true, since in every iteration, `x0` will get reset to `-3`. The loop will never exit. Your program hangs.

You need to move the `x0 = -3` to before the loop, like this:

```
x0 = -3
do while (x0 < 11) 
    call findbracket(x0, a, b)
    x0 = x0 + 1
end do
```

That way, `x0` won't get reset to `-3` in every iteration of the loop and will eventually become larger than `11` so that the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

An "infinite" for loop is achieved as follows:

```
do

   ** Some executable statements

   if (conditional_statement) exit
end do
```

In brief, a set of statements are executed repetitively until the conditional statement is satisfied, that is,

```
conditional_statement .eqv. .true.
```

When this occurs, program control jumps to the next executable statement immediately following the `do` construct.

Comment: FYI, infinite loops are preferred over `do while` to aid optimization flags.

Comment: I tried do x0 =-3 and `if (x0 == 10) then exit` but it still gets into an infinite loop.. Sorry to write all codes in one line

Comment: That simply tells you that `x0` never increments to `10`. One of your lower routines are therefore to blame.